# Aligning table cells using height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align some table cells to an image by setting the height of each row. Sadly it does not seem to work properly, as it does not use the whole percentage for the rows. The table should be 725px high with each cell evenly spread out, but it is not. How can I ensure that they are spread out evenly?

https://jsfiddle.net/hpL127zr/1/

I am setting the height like this.

```
tr {
  height: 2.8571428571429%;

}
```

I know I could use height out, but this will allow the rows to become to high if the text is to long (multi line).

Answer (score 0):

There is only 35 column in the table from your fiddle and the percentage you're using correspond to 40 column.

So just add :

```
<tr><td>lala</td></tr>
<tr><td>lala</td></tr>
<tr><td>lala</td></tr>
<tr><td>lala</td></tr>
<tr><td>lala</td></tr>
```

And with 40 column it seems to be working perfectly.

https://jsfiddle.net/hpL127zr/2/